# Find out how often OTHER apps crashed on Android

Tags: android, crash, logging

My manager asks if it's possible for an app to learn how many times OTHER apps that are installed on the Android device have crashed.

From what I understand about sandboxing the apps, this shouldn't be possible. Is maybe the Android OS writing somewhere into logs which apps crashed, when, for what reason (e.g. stack trace saved)? If yes, one could parse them (possibly even on a non-rooted phone, if permissions allow).

This should work for just any kinds of other apps, from AndroidMarket or not, and not only those we developed ourselves.

Thanks!

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/alogcat/ look at source ... all you need to do is log parsing ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My manager asks if it's possible for an app to learn how many times OTHER apps that are installed on the Android device have crashed.

Some apps will allow their stack traces for unhandled exceptions to be written to LogCat, which you can read if you have the `READ_LOGS` permission. Ideally, *few* production applications do this, as one can argue that it's a bit of a security issue. Those that have their own mechanism for reporting unhandled exceptions (e.g., ACRA) will not necessarily log their data to LogCat, and you have no way about finding out whether or not they "crashed".

Comment: Thanks! How long do the logs in logcat stay? I mean, it will grow to megabytes after some time and would clog space if kept on the phone forever, won't it? When I view it from Eclipse, it gets cleaned up after maybe 10-20 mins. If so, I'd need a service which keeps parsing LogCat once in a while. Am I thinking over the right lines?

Comment: They'd prefer an app which just runs once, and can tell what apps had crashed before this app was installed. If LogCat gets cleaned up regularly, this wouldn't be possible, right?

Comment: @iseeall: "How long do the logs in logcat stay?" -- not long. It's a 64KB ring buffer, so older entries get replaced with newer ones. "I'd need a service which keeps parsing LogCat once in a while" -- triggered by `AlarmManager`, yes. "They'd prefer an app which just runs once, and can tell what apps had crashed before this app was installed." -- if it crashed in the last few minutes, that might work. Personally, I don't like apps with `READ_LOGS`, and so expect some push-back from users.